# multiple if else statements php

Tags: php, if-statement

I have inputs `$a,$b,$c,$d` and `$e` and outputs `$f` and `$g`.

Based on the combinations of values of the inputs the values of outputs will vary. 
There are around 400 possible combinations.

Is there a better way to write this rather than writing 400 if else statements?

I'm writing in `php`

```
if ($a == 'aaa' && $b == 'baaa' && $c == 'abc' && $d == 'zzz' && $e = 'eee') 
{
    $f = 'Positive';
    $g = 'Negative';
} 
else if ..... // Have 400 such scenarios.
```

Comment: More code might help... or some more context

Comment: Loops? But again, we can't help if you don't provide your code. **Edit**, loops would be best.

Comment: It depends heavily on how systematic the rules are. If they are not at all 400 `if` is just as god as any other mapping of random a => b, but if you can make rules based on the input it's possible to simplify. YOu can compare that with images. As data they look like random data but they are actually 3 interleaved black/white images that relate slightly and change little in any direction so knowing that you can simplify, but without knowing it its random and unpredictable.

Comment: Can you give us the relation between the variables and why they `$f` and `$g` as that and some more terms? How did you know `$f` was `'Positive'`?? It seems that with just two variables and positive/negative you have about 4 outcomes.

Comment: I have an excel sheet that has the input / output relationship. If I spend a lot of time looking for input relationships, I may find some and reduce this number by 30 - 40 but it may not be worth it. Is there a way I can define these use cases "one below the other" in a file and make my program traverse through that file rather than writing if statements (that may be cleaner). Sorry I'm running my imagination. Could you point me to a documentation / way. Just looking for a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: a,b,c,d and e are not booleans..

Comment: Maybe try to save that excel sheet as csv then read it with php script and iterate trough.

Comment: @Mr_KoKa Thats what I'm trying to do. Putting the results in a database table and traverse the rows to find the result.

Comment: @Ank, if you will have that database then it should be straight forward, if you have csv there is way to read it too, if you choose any of this approach and still in trouble update your post with example data in your excel file.

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge there is no other option than if else. But, I suggest an algorithmic approach:
You can concatenate all the items $a $b ... in just one variable $concat, and then you test your condition on this last one with a :
Switch ($concat){case: ...}
Maybe you can minimize the number of cases :
Example: if $a == 'abbc' then $f='positive' for any value $b $c ...etc
You can also create a matrix(400,2) (2 columns and 400 rows) first column is the value of $concat the second one is the value tu put in $f. This matrix can be filled in a loop and used as below : 
$f=matrix[(string)$concat]
The matrix can be filled from a text file like an excel sheet ;)